# how can I create a yes no cancel dialog in zenity

Tags: zenity

how can I add a button to the --question dialog ?
in python, tkmessagebox allows it,
on windows messagebox also allows it,
but I can't find how to do it with zenity.

Answer (score 4):

you can't. zenity only allows 2 option questions.